# Implementing a simple replication tool

Tags: java, spring-integration, replication, jmx, database-replication

Our team is working on a project that is intended to transfer data between oracle databases over a DMZ periodically , and for some reason we are not allowed to use DBMS solutions for data replication between databases. we must develop a simple replication tool and its monitoring system suitable to our scenario by Java technologies. i have had a look on many things which i thought can help us in this project like Spring Integration , Spring Batch , Web Service , JMS and Message Queue , JMX  ... but i can't find a clue where i should start.


Please guide me what are best options and best practices which i can follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use some CDC (change data capture) solution that is analyzing changes in the database (Redo Logs) and applying the changes to the target - like Oracle GoldenGate, Streams, SAP Replication Server, Attunity, etc.
2. Use an ETL tool - that is periodically making SELECT statemetns in the source, and copying the whole data sets to the target.

Comment: Thanks a lot , two more question , question one: Can SymmetricDS be right tool? and question two: Is developing a simple ETL tool from scratch a crazy idea?

Comment: I don't know this tool. You have to make a POC and test it if it is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Adam for guidance :)

Comment: Reza, I work at JumpMind, the company the distributes SymmetricDS and it could be used for your use case and it is based on CDC as Adam mentions above.   It does use triggers to capture changes rather than log based replication.   We also have an ETL tool (METL) if you wanted to look into the more scheduled approach rather than near real time.   We do offer a trial and a POC version if this is something your interested in taking a deeper look.